# For Advaitins, what is the point of vedic chants?

Tags: mantras, vedanta, advaita, vedic-chanting

Most nominal advaitins I know (and especially brahmin followers of the various Shankara maths) hold that chanting of vedic hymns is valuable. What's the point?

I believe even the math gurus hold vedic chanting to be valuable.

Comment: vibrations. The whole universe is vibrations. The exact intonations of the mantras are meant to put the mind and body into a harmonic vibration with the results desired. 'AUM' is God Itself. Chanting AUM is the only true worship.

Answer (score 1):

Practical value of chanting for the society/culture is for preserving the Vedas generations over generations. Chanting for preservation has some benefits over written/printing form because chanting also preserves the vocalization (which is very important to preserve the meaning). Ved-pathi brahmins not only chant Vedas like a song, they chant it with exact swaras. It is also not simple reading of Vedas. It also involves techniques like Ghan-path which involves breaking compound words in to its constituent individual words (called sandhi). Preservation by chanting has social effect of father-son, guru-shisya bonds.
Although, the ved-pathi brahmins has strong beliefs that chanting vedic mantras are not same the same as memorizing it. They do it as a part of performing ved-puja. It is noted that memorizing sanskrit slokas improves the intelligence.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! We insist on citing references from scriptures. You can read more from the help centre as well as [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)